# appcfg.py update <appname> no longer working after GAE update. (OSX Terminal)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm using `appcfg.py update <appname>` to upload/update my app, but instead I am getting this message in my terminal:

```
owner:~ owner$ appcfg.py update kratosapp
You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
different account:

  $ gcloud config set account <account name>

to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

When I try using the two recommended actions:

```
  $ gcloud config set account <account name>
  OR
  $ gcloud auth login
```

I get the following error on my command line:

```
-bash: $: command not found
```

I'm not sure what is going on. I've tried establishing the Sym Link. This happened after my most recent update of the GAE software on the mac.

Comment: When entering commands, you don't include the $ - that's just to indicate that you run the command following it at a shell prompt.

Comment: @lantius, thank you sir. Do you know why this step has become necessary? I was using the `appcfg.py update ...` perfectly fine before the update.

Comment: All the Google Cloud Platform products are centralizing all the command line work in a single tool called the Google Cloud SDK (gcloud) which will be the definitive way of doing remote interactions, for example in App Engine for deploying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "$" indicates that you should paste what follows into a new command line.

You always need authentication, but your old credentials may have expired or have been revoked.